# get column name for PDO from query

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I want to convert my code from working with mysql to pdo.
and i was looking for an equivalent function for mysql_field_name but i didn't find any, except this function  PDOStatement::getColumnMeta, but PHP documentation  say it's "EXPERIMENTAL" and it won't work with future release of PHP.
so i did this work.

assuming i have this table

```
id         name        age       city
1          ad          25         a      
2          im          23         b
3          sh          21         c
```

and i wanna select only the name and city

```
 name       city
  ad          a      
  im          b
  sh          c 

    $link = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=db_name;charset=utf8",user,pass);
    $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES, false);
    $link->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    $query="SELECT name,city FROM  table" ;
    $result = link->prepare($query);
    $result->execute();
    $result ->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

    foreach ($result as $value){
        $tablename =array_keys($value);
    }

    echo "<table><tr>";
    foreach ($tablename  as $key)
        echo "<td>".$key."</td>";
    echo "</tr></table>";
```

i'm not sure if this's the right way to do it.
or if there's a PDO function can do this work

Comment: I feel it worth pointing out that the documentation does *not* say `getColumnMeta()` "won't work," it says it "may change."

Answer (score 2):

You can get column name like this

```
 foreach ($result as $row){
    foreach($row as $col_name => $val)
     {
     echo "$col_name == $val<br />";    
     }
    echo"Next Row<br />";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have table called **table**

```
$select = $db->query('SELECT * FROM table');

$total_column = $select->columnCount();
var_dump($total_column);

for ($counter = 0; $counter < $total_column; $counter ++) {
    $meta = $select->getColumnMeta($counter);
    $column[] = $meta['name'];
}
```

$column will contain complete list of columns, and column meta is a function which will help you to get column properties.

Thanks
Amit

Answer (score -1):

```
$q = $dbh->prepare("DESCRIBE tablename");
$q->execute();
$table_fields = $q->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_COLUMN);
```

Comment: i want to get field name from a query, this will get all the fields's name